# Problem in Using more than one directory in fuerte

Tags: ros, ros-workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I have installed hydro and fuerte and having problem when i want to use more than one directory in fuerte. I have made 2 directories named,fuerte_workspace and ros_workspace, and added them to my bashrc. but my ROS doesn't seem to recognize my ros_workspace and I can just roscd to packages in fuerte_workspace. what shoul I do? Thanks for any help. My ending lines in bashrc are as follows:

> ```
>  source `rospack find gazebo`/setup.bash
> ```

```
 source /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash
 export ROS_PAcKAGE_PATH=~/dev/rosbook:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
>      export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/ros_workspace:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
```

> ```
>  export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
> >      export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/drh-robotics-ros/ros/ardros:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
>  export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/VSLAMDIR:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
> >      export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/Navigation_Mohammad:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
>
>  source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash
>  source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash
> ```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201458/problem-in-using-more-than-one-directory-in-fuerte/) by [Morteza](https://answers.ros.org/users/20070/morteza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2015-01-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You first source the fuerte setup.bash, then add stuff to  ROS_PACKAGE_PATH and afterwards source the hydro setup.bash. If I'm not mistaken, that overwrites your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH settings from before. You'll want to first call setup.bash files and afterwards set ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. You also have a typo in your first export line (lower case "c").

It's generally advisable to use rosinstall and wstool  for setting up a workspace, as this means you don't have to manually define ROS_PACKAGE_PATH as you have done. See for example [this Q/A](http://answers.ros.org/question/111746/checkout-of-packages-into-a-catkin-workspace/).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1